# Termux MariaDB all command broken

Tags: mariadb, termux

```
    MariaDB [(none)]> select database()
        -> ;
    +------------+
    | database() |
    +------------+
    | NULL       |
    +------------+                                          1 row in set (0.001 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]> select user();
    +-------------------+
    | user()            |
    +-------------------+
    | u0_a548@localhost |
    +-------------------+
    1 row in set (0.001 sec)
    
    MariaDB [(none)]>
```

I use terminal Termux in Android but very hard login in this database. My problem is not get create or insert run ask in database why? Im try use write command but all time is syntax error or nothig yet and not add on database. Please help correct this im try `mysql -u $(whoami)` or `mysql -u root` i don't know password is Termux in database MariaDB?? Why all command is broken??

Comment: looks like the user account you are using has no permissions to create. You will need to login as a privilaged user, like `root` Did you setup that database or are you using one setup by someone else

Comment: Or have you tried to create a database at all or have you tried to use an existing one? database() function returns null if no default database is selected. To select a default database use the `use dbname;` statement